# Go-to approach to provide css and csjs resources in a custom xpages osgi library

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I'm having difficulties finding the proper approach to provide css and csjs resources in my custom xpages Library. I was not able to find any good info on how to package such resources with my osgi plugin.

I took a look at the extlib implementation, but couldn't really make much of what is happening in the ResourceHandler parts (and if those are even related to what I need, actually). So what steps are necessary if one wanted to deploy, say, a dojo dijit within the library?

Comment: How about the Bootstrap4XPages implementation (https://github.com/markleusink/Bootstrap4XPages-1)? Maybe you can figure that one out: it's a lot smaller than the ExtLib and one of its purposes is to provide css/ csjs. This blogpost (http://www.gregorbyte.com/2014/07/bootswatches-from-osgi-fragment.html) has some good info too.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for nudging me twards the bootstrap4xpages project. I already took a look at it before, but obviously not close enough. I more or less -copied- extracted the approach from there and with some fiddling around it finally worked! I added the answer below and hope I didn't forget anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What did it for me:
Create an [OSGi Plugin Activator](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fruntime%2FPlugin.html); in the constructor, load a custom `ExtLibLoaderExtension` that basically sits on top of the Extlib resource handling. To use that, the resources need to go into a subfolder of "/resources/web/extlib" with a name that is specified by this very `ExtLibLoaderExtension`.

The Activator:

```
public class MyCustomActivator extends Plugin {

    public static MyCustomActivator instance;

    public MyCustomActivator() {
        instance = this;

        ExtLibLoaderExtension.getExtensions().add(new MyCustomLoader());
    }
}
```

The ExtLibLoaderExtension:

```
public class MyCustomLoader extends ExtLibLoaderExtension {

    public MyCustomLoader(){

    }

    @Override
    public Bundle getOSGiBundle() {
        return MyCustomActivator.instance.getBundle();
    }

    @Override
    public URL getResourceURL(HttpServletRequest request, String name) {
        if(name.startsWith("[put subfolder name here]")) {
            String path = ExtlibResourceProvider.BUNDLE_RES_PATH_EXTLIB+name;
            return ExtLibUtil.getResourceURL(
                MyCustomActivator.instance.getBundle(), path);
         }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Make sure your resources folder is included in the **Build** section of your `plugin.xml`. On the **Overview** Tab, provide the Activator class in the section **General Information** on the top left. After all this, you can access your resources from a Webbrowser by using the */xsp/.ibmxspres/.extlib/[put subfolder name here]/* junction once you've deployed the updateSite and restarted the http task.